# How can I install dot net on linux wine and cross over?

Tags: linux, .net-framework, wine

How can I install dot net on linux wine and cross over?

Comment: "cross-over to the other side" Led Zeppelin

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.jswindle.com/index.php/Visual_Studio
http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iAppId=892
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=897849

Answer (score 2):

The .NET framework isn't **meant** to run on Linux, however Visual Studio can be with a few tweaks pointed out in SjB's links. You'll want [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) for optimal compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Disclaimer:*** This answer contains information which might be outdated soon and I could forget to update it. Please consult the provided links for current informations.

As John and SjB pointed out are there two ways for this. **But** (and that's a big one) whatever way you choose, you'll have to stick with 3.0.

**Wine**
You can install up to 3.0 under WINE without any problems (at least according to the [AppDB entry](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2586)). All newer versions have currently bugs in their installers and will not work.

**Mono**
[The free port of the .NET Framework](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is [compatible to 3.5](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility), you can even take applications and *just* run them under Linux, without the need to recompile them. Unfortunately, there are some classes and functions (f.e. the HasRows() Property of the ODBCDataReader) which aren't implemented by now, and may throw an exception. Additionally to it, the Forms-Interface will look a little strange and out of place within Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to cross over. I'm a c# developer and its my bread and butter stuff. So a few things holding me back are VS2010, Sharepoint, SQL and the infamous IIS.

Just to be clear .net is not the problem! Mono is (at times) an even better implementation of the .net framework than true .net. Don't believe me - check out mailing - Mono long ago discovered to send a QUIT command to the server. .net only does this in v4.

I think the way forward is to setup an additional windows server, develop on that using RDC. Virtualization will only get you so far, and if you're like me (no patience) you'll want stuff to run as quick as possible natively. RDCing into a quick server might be a good compromise for now.

Your client pc then can be completely linux based, or some apps running under wine.

Failing that, plan a longer term migration away from MS tech. You could still use Mono, just don't use any MS tech. This sounds like a huge challenge and it is. But the best thing about this is you'll never get involved in Sharepoint solutions.

Disclaimer, I'm not a fanboy, but I think Linux has some great potential for more specialized computer users.